# Regular rings and finite flat modules

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, ac.commutative-algebra, flatness

Let $A$ be a Noetherian domain. Assume $f:A\rightarrow B$ is an injective homomorphism making $B$ into a finite flat module over $A$. If $B$ is regular is $A$ regular as well? I played with some examples: finite covers of elliptic curves, finite field extensions and the normalization of the cuspidal curve.

There is a sort of a converse statement, namely if $B$ is not assumed flat then if $A$ is regular $B$ is flat (Thm 23.1 in Matsumura).

Comment: This follows from the fact a finitely generated module $M$ over $A$ is flat (hence projective) if and only if $M\otimes_A B$ is flat over $B$. Thus, using the fact that every finitely generated module over $B$ has a finite projective resolution, since $B$ is regular, it follows that the same holds for $A$ and thus $A$ is regular.

Comment: @Mohan Is the following what you have in mind? For a finitely generated $A$-module $M$, take a resolution $\dotsb \to F_{2} \to F_{1} \to F_{0} \to M$ by finite free $A$-modules, then $\ker(F_{d} \to F_{d-1}) \otimes_{A} B$ is flat for some $d$ by [Tag 00NE](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NE) and [Tag 00NT](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00NT)?

Comment: I think this is also Thm 23.7(i) in Matsumura. The statement there is stated for a local flat homomorphism, but regularity and flatness are local properties.